# How to list children of a project in a pom.xml?

Tags: xml, maven-2, build, parent-child, pom.xml

I know it is possible to define a parent for a project in the pom.xml but can I explicitly define the children of a project in maven 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's called 'modules' in maven. So under the tag modules, you have the tag module with the name of the module aka child.

[Maven modules](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html)

[Example](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule-sect-simple-parent.html)

Answer (score 1):

I will give you an example:

```
            <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
                <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
                <groupId>de.something.pr.pr-system</groupId>
                <artifactId>pr-models</artifactId>
                <version>T03-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
                <description>PR Processing</description>

                <parent>
                    <groupId>de.something.pr</groupId>
                    <artifactId>pr-system</artifactId>
                    <version>T03-SNAPSHOT</version>
                </parent>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>de.something.pr.pr-system</groupId>
                        <artifactId>pr-common</artifactId>
                        <version>T24-SNAPSHOT</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </project>
```

Comment: This is really a bad example, cause you don't use real maven versions (http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/version-rules.html). The parent should be located after modelVersion and before groupId/artifactId etc.

Comment: @khmarbaise, it may be not fit to the version rules for mojo plugin, although i used maven2 for long time writing my poms as you see, worked for me. If i would like to use those plugins, you are right i need to be consistent with those rules